# Issue with ISO 8601 in Android API level 23

Tags: java, android

I've issue in format of java for ISO 8601, I'm using this code

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
//yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.shh:mm
Date date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
String cDate = format.format(date);
Log.d("Date","Date is " + cDate);
```

My result is:

```
Date is 2019-04-03T04:37:52+0000
```

if I'm using this format `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ`.  And the result is:

```
Date is 2019-04-03T04:49:33.3304:49
```

if I'm using this format `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.shh:mm`. I've been tried my solutions but not is giving me my desired solution.
My desired solution is `2008-09-15T15:53:00+05:00`. I try Offset but it's not working for API level 23, It's only for API level 28.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tim was right but his given pattern works for java, Not for that java which is in android.
For Android java use this pattern

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ");
```

Then out put will be

```
Date is 2019-04-03T08:29:27+00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the format mask you should be using:

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for `SimpleDateFormat`, we can see that `X` represents the ISO 8601 time zone, which shows the timezone in terms of hours shifted from GMT.

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX");
format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Africa/Cairo"));
Date date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
String cDate = format.format(date);
System.out.println("Date is " + cDate);

Date is 2019-04-03T06:41:30+02:00
```

Note that I needed to assign a time zone other than `GMT`, because `GMT` just returns `Z` for the time zone.

Comment: Thanks for edit my question and your respected answer, But app crash and shows Unknown pattern character 'X'

Comment: It is [working in this Java demo](https://ideone.com/nY1TVi).  AFAIK Android runs on a fork of Java 7, so I am surprised that the above code is not working for you.

Comment: I just checked the [JavaDoc](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat) for Android's SDF, and my code should be working.

Comment: I'm also surprised. :(

Comment: Tim please check it, i just copy your code and paste in new pan, But you can visit it https://ideone.com/I6HRGd  why it's showing error. Because i'm not importing import java.text.*; In my android app i'm using import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone; ant issue with it?

Comment: You are missing an import: `import java.text.*;`

Comment: Not as far as I know.  The `java.text` package should be part of the code Android Java SDK.  You just need that `import` statement in the source file using `SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: I can't really offer any other advice at this point, without sitting down in front of your Android Studio (which I obviously can't do).  Maybe someone else will be able to completely resolve your problem.

Comment: The documentation states that the `X` pattern letter for ISO-8601 timezones is only supported on API level 24 and above. OP is trying to run this on API level 23.

Comment: @Michael Thanks for clarifying that.  But moving forward, most Android users would probably be at level 24 or above (I think).